# vba condtional format loop failing

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have this code that almost works:

```
Sub condFormat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Columns("B:B").FormatConditions.Delete
    ws.Columns("B:B").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(B1)>100"
    ws.Columns("B:B").FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next
End Sub
```

But it won't update the actual cell properly.

I end up with stuff like:

```
=LEN(B65517)>100
```

in column b cells.

How can I revise this to reference the correct cells in column B?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code exactly and it works perfect in excel 2010

Comment: I'm currently on 2003.  The formatting doesn't seem to line up correctly.  for example sheet(1) cell B1 conditional formatting shows =LEN(IV65531)>100

Comment: If anyone can think of a different way to do this maybe using EVALUATE, please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing a loop since I couldn't get it to work the other way:

```
Sub condFormat()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range, c As Range
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Columns("B:B").FormatConditions.Delete
    Set myRange = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    For Each c In myRange
    If Len(c) > 100 Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Cell references can get shifted based on the currently selected cell.

You can add an absolute reference to the B column:

> ws.Columns("B:B").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression,
> Formula1:="=LEN($B1)>100"

But the easiest way is to probably explicitly select a cell, probably A1:

> ws.Activate
>
> ws.Cells(1, 1).Select

[Here is a link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895562) from Microsoft explaining the issue.

Comment: Adding `Range("A1"). select` after the for and `Formula1:="=LEN($B1)>100"` worked

Comment: sigh... It still does weird things.  Now on some sheets it is working fine on others it doesn't.  I'm not sure what the difference between sheets is.